# Using bootstrap sass, some variables are not being overridden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, overriding

I'm starting a new project and I'm using bootstrap-sass for the front end layout tool.

I'm trying to override some of the variables in bootstrap sass and while I can override some of them, other's aren't changing.

I created a simple template to look at each of the main color overrides as I change them:

```
<div class="well">
    <ul>
        <li><dropzone></dropzone></li>
        <li><gallery></gallery></li>
        <li><location></location></li>
        <li><locations></locations></li>
        <li><pp-image></pp-image></li>
        <li><map></map></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        test
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

And then in my scss entry point `main.scss` I created my variable overrides and then imported bootstrap-sass:

```
$color1: #D800E5;
$color2: #010B3A;
$color3: #2300F5;
$color4: #FB0026;
$color5: #B34D30;
$color6: #FBFEFB;

$gray-base:              green;
$gray-darker:            lighten($gray-base, 13.5%);
$gray-dark:              lighten($gray-base, 20%);
$gray:                   lighten($gray-base, 33.5%);
$gray-light:             lighten($gray-base, 46.7%);
$gray-lighter:           lighten($gray-base, 93.5%);

$brand-primary:         darken($color1, 6.5%);
$brand-success:         $color3; 
$brand-info:            orange; // i also tried using regular color assignments in case it was a variable issue. these don't work either
$brand-warning:         green;
$brand-danger:          yellow;


$icon-font-path: '~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

body{
    background-color:$color2;
    color: $color2;
}
```

When I review the template in browser, the primary-color override worked, but the gray override and the status based overrides did not:

[image: example of issue]

I'm still digging around in docs to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I figured it may be obvious for someone who's more familiar with front end styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `well` class on the element you want to see in green instead of gray.

But the default color for well [is defined as](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L768):

```
$well-bg:                     #f5f5f5 !default;
$well-border:                 darken($well-bg, 7%) !default;
```

So if you want to change the color of the well, you should change the color of `$well-bg`. If you want to see for what elements the `$gray-base` color is used, search for `$gray` in [this file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss).

## Edit by OP

Note that the names of the variables that you are looking to override are found in the file: `_bootstrap-variables.scss`.

If you're pulling in bootstrap-sass via npm (which I'm doing in this project) that file can be found at

```
node_modules/bootstrap-sass/templates/project/_bootstrap-variables.scss
```

Comment: Ahh, ok I see what's going on. Based on your answer I realize that I was trying to override variables based on the wrong bootstrap-sass file. I was looking at the file `node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` for the names of the variables to override. Per your answer I realized that I should be looking at the `node_modules/bootstrap-sass/templates/project/_bootstrap-variables.scss` for those var names. I updated the vars in my scss and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should override this variable `$panel-success-border, $panel-success-text, $panel-success-heading-bg, $panel-success-border` for success panel and similar for others.